# how to integrate facebook messenger and default response in dialogflow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to add a clickable link for my chatbot response in dialogflow but in default response, I can't add a clickable link and if I try with facebook messenger how can I integrate both response i.e facebook messenger and default response for my bot to integrate on website.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, so I will answer it according to my understanding. 
1. You should integrate Dialogflow with Facebook messenger no matter what you want to do. It is a very simple process and here's the link from documentation: [ingegrate DF with FB](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/integrations/facebook) 
2. You can add clickable link (card) in Inline editor. Here's the function

```
function yourFunctionName(agent) {
 agent.add(`Hey! This is header message`);
 agent.add(new Card({
     title: `Welcome to our website`,
     imageUrl: 'https:<link to image>.png',  // remove if you don't want to add image
     text: `This is just for testing`,
     buttonText: 'Link', // Button title
     buttonUrl: 'http:<Your link>'
   })
 );
```

I am assuming you understand the basics of using that function.

Comment: so if I use facebook messenger as response I m not able to shift my small talk and basic interaction which are present in default response of the bot when I host the whole chatbot on my website

Comment: You should be able to do that. I do not see any reason for not being able